# A logical "or" inside a Selenium test case

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

Assuming I would like test for a default Apache server response at one point, and I would like to make it platform agnostic.

For CentOS I have:

```
  def test_web_interface(self):
    self.driver.get(DEST_URL)
    self.assertIn('Apache HTTP Server Test Page powered by CentOS', self.driver.title)
```

for Debian I have:

```
  def test_web_interface(self):
    self.driver.get(DEST_URL)
    self.assertIn('Apache2 Debian Default Page: It works', self.driver.title)
```

The assertion string is the only difference in two tests.

If I would like to avoid passing the "tested platform"-argument to the test, apart from checking the common string like `Apache` or `Page`, what would be a canonical way of including a disjunction inside such a unit test?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the kind of solution that you have in mind, and is likely not cannonical, but I have solved a similar issue by using environment variables. For example you could do:

```
import os

def test_web_interface(self):
    self.driver.get(DEST_URL)
    platform = os.environ['TEST_PLATFORM']
    titles = {
        'centos': 'Apache HTTP Server Test Page powered by CentOS',
        'debian': 'Apache2 Debian Default Page: It works'
    }
    self.assertIn(titles.get('platform'), self.driver.title)
```

This way you can add more platforms if necessary, and all you need to do is set the environment variable in a config or elsewhere on each platform:

```
import os
os.environ['TEST_PLATFORM'] = 'whatever_platform'
```

Comment: If the Apache server is on a remote machine, make sure you identify the OS on the remote machine, and not the OS where the test is running.

Answer (score 1):

That's a test in `unittest`, right? (guessing so by the method name)

If so, you could use `assertTrue()`, and check is the text in one of the expected values:

```
def test_web_interface(self):
    self.driver.get(DEST_URL)
    titles = ( 'Apache HTTP Server Test Page powered by CentOS',  'Apache2 Debian Default Page: It works')
    self.assertTrue(self.driver.title in titles)
```

And if my `unittest` guess was not correct, you could use the regular python `assert`:

```
assert self.driver.title in titles
```